# Matrix Grid where center is 0, 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

Trying to get my head around the maths for this one. I have a grid in which I want to know far away the block is from the center.

I have a function which currently is the following:

```
let grid = [];

function buildGrid(c, r) {
    for(let i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
        for(let j = 1; j <= c; j++) {
        }
    }
}
buildGrid(5, 3);
```

What I want it to grid to output is the following:

```
let grid = [{x: -2, y: -1},
            {x: -1, y: -1},
            {x: 0, y: -1},
            {x: 1, y: -1},
            {x: 2, y: -1},
            {x: -2, y: 0},
            {x: -1, y: 0},
            {x: 0, y: 0},
            {x: 1, y: 0},
            {x: 2, y: 0},
            {x: -2, y: 1},
            {x: -1, y: 1},
            {x: 0, y: 1},
            {x: 1, y: 1},
            {x: 2, y: 1}];
```

Or

```
 -2, -1 | -1, -1 | 0, -1 | 1, -1 | 2, -1
 -------|--------|-------|-------|-------
 -2, 0  | -1, 0  | 0, 0  | 1, 0  | 2, 0
 -------|--------|-------|-------|-------
 -2, 1  | -1, 1  | 0, 1  | 1, 1  | 2, 1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for positive flow like `buildGrid(5, 3)` or `buildGrid(7, 5)` or `buildGrid(5, 3)` , means even number greater then 1 no other condition added. I assume you can do this at your self. If you get and issue share all conditions with sample data.

```js
function buildGrid(c, r) {
  var c_less = (c-1)/2;// You need to modify here to add all condition 
  var r_less = (r-1)/2;// You need to modify here to add all condition
  //console.log(c_less);
  var newArr = [];
  for(let j = -r_less; j <= r_less; j++) {
    var str = [];
    for(let i = -c_less; i <= c_less; i++) {
      str.push({x:i,y:j});
    }
    newArr.push(str);
  }
  document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newArr);
  console.log(newArr);
}
buildGrid(5, 3);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

`var c_less = (c-1)/2;`// You need to modify here to add all other conditions

Comment: Absolutely genius way of solving this. Thanks!